# How do i search in a telnet session output with re a string where x is a number between 1 and 99999?

Tags: python, python-2.7, module, telnet, telnetlib

```
import getpass
import sys
import telnetlib
import re
import smtplib

print "Pasul 1"

HOST = "route-views.routeviews.org"
user = "rviews"
password = ""

tn = telnetlib.Telnet(HOST)

tn.read_until("login: ", 5)
tn.write(user + "\r\n")

tn.read_until("Password: ", 5)
tn.write(password + "\r\n")

print tn.read_until(">", 10)
tn.write("show ip route 192.0.2.1"+"\r\n")

y = tn.read_until("free", 10)
print y
tn.write("exit"+ "\r\n")

tn.close()

print "Pasul 2"

for x in range(1,99999):
    m = re.search(' Known via "bgp xxxxx"', y)
    if m:
        print (m.group(0))
        break
    else:
        print False
        break
```

x has to be a number between 1 and 99999
If i write ' Known via "bgp 6447"' it will find and print it, but if i write ' Known via "bgp xxxxx"', it returns false. Anybody knows why?

The output is this:

route-views>

show ip route 192.0.2.1

Routing entry for 192.0.2.1/32

Known via "bgp 6447", distance 20, metric 0

Tag 19214, type external

Last update from 208.74.64.40 4w0d ago

Routing Descriptor Blocks:

- 208.74.64.40, from 208.74.64.40, 4w0d ago

  Route metric is 0, traffic share count is 1

  AS Hops 1

  Route tag 19214

  MPLS label: none

route-views>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using regexp in a totally wrong way, try changing the whole this section:

```
for x in range(1,99999):
    m = re.search(' Known via "bgp xxxxx"', y)
    if m:
        print (m.group(0))
        break
    else:
        print False
        break
```

with following:

```
m = re.search(r'Known via "bgp \d{0,5}"', y)
if m:
   print m.group(0)
else:
   print False
```

And notice `r` before expression, it's important here.

Probably you should read this docs for python `re` module: https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html

**Upd.** By the way, your version does not works because `x` inside string is interpreted as literal `"x"`, not the value of variable `x`. If you want to put a variable inside a string you should use formatting like in this example:

```
x = 12345
print ' Known via "bgp {}"'.format(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

It gives me 'True' if I test

```
>>> y = ' Known via "bgp xxxxx"'
>>> re.search('Known via "bgp xxxxx"', y)

>>> if x:
...     print "yes"
...
yes
```

Comment: you did not read everything, x is a number between 1 and 99999, in the 'show ip route' it's like this: Known via "bgp 6447", i need something to search with the ' Known via "bgp xxxxx"' and return me Known via "bgp 6447"